# DT Version 0.3 (Newest) not rendering Table

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a question about the newest DT Version (0.3). After making an update from DT Version 0.2.20 to 0.3, a table after pressing the `actionButton` is not rendering, not giving any error. After changing my code and implementing `eventReactive`, a table is rendered. However, I am just curious what has happened that the new version of DT (0.3) is not working well with my old approach or `isolate`?

Here is code which is going to exactly show this problem:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(radioButtons("buttons","", choices = c("iris","mtcars")),
                 actionButton("button1", "Choose"),
                 DT::dataTableOutput('tbl'),
                 DT::dataTableOutput('tbl2')),
  server = function(input, output) {

    #1st possibility with eventReactive WORKING WITH THE NEW DT VERSION (0.3)


    data <- eventReactive(input$button1,
                          {if(input$buttons  == "mtcars"){mtcars}else{
                            iris}
                          })

    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(data())}
    )

    #2nd possibility with isolate WHICH IS NOT WORKING WITH DT = 0.3 BUT IT IS WORKING WITH DT = 0.2.20!! 

    output$tbl2 <- renderDataTable ({
      withProgress(message = 'Processing...', style = "old",value = 0, 
                   {

                     for (i in 1:10) {
                       incProgress(1/30)
                       Sys.sleep(0.1)
                     }
                     if( input$button1 == 0)
                     {
                       return()
                     }
                     isolate({
                       data <- if(input$buttons  == "mtcars"){mtcars}else{
                         iris}
                       datatable(data)
                     })})})


  }
)
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug of DT. I'm investigating it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a bug in **DT** 0.3 (which has been reported in [#488](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/488) and [#489](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/489)) and I have [fixed it](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/commit/8d2518435422a30ad0bac17a95373a687b0eb4e2) yesterday. For now, please try the development version of **DT**:

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')
```